# sqlalchemy hybrid_property and expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can not understand the expressions. How to get the following code to work?

```
class OperationType(Enum):
    MINUS = 1
    MINUS_CORR = 2
    PLUS = 3
    PLUS_CORR = 4
```

group operation by type

```
BALANCE_PLUS_OPERATIONS = [
    OperationType.PLUS.value,
    OperationType.PLUS_CORR.value
]

BALANCE_MINUS_OPERATIONS = [
    OperationType.MINUS.value,
    OperationType.MINUS_CORR.value
]
```

Operation model

```
class Operation(Model):

    __tablename__ = 'operation'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    operation_type = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False)
    amount = Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship('User', backref='operation', uselist=False)
```

User model

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    operations = relationship("Operation", backref="users")

    @hybrid_property
    def balance(self):
        plus = sum(op.amount for op in self.operations if op.operation_type in BALANCE_PLUS_OPERATIONS)
        minus = sum(op.amount for op in self.operations if op.operation_type in BALANCE_MINUS_OPERATIONS)
        return plus - minus

    @balance.expression
    def balance(cls):
        p = select([func.sum(Operation.amount).label('BALANCE_PLUS_OPERATIONS')]) \
                .where(Operation.operation_type.in_(BALANCE_PLUS_OPERATIONS)) \
                .where(User.id == cls.id) \
                .as_scalar()
        m = select([func.sum(Operation.amount).label('BALANCE_MINUS_OPERATIONS')]) \
                .where(Operation.operation_type.in_(BALANCE_MINUS_OPERATIONS)) \
                    .where(User.id == cls.id) \
                    .as_scalar()
        return select([p - m]).label('BALANCE')
```

The expression is wrong and will produce the wrong result:

```
users = User.query.filter_by(balance=51).all()
for u in users:
    print(u, u.balance)
```

print:

```
<User(foo@bar.com)> 51
<User(bar@foor.com)> 0
```

but i expected only one record:

```
<User(foo@bar.com)> 51
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to explain (1) what you expected to happen, (2) what error you're getting (or how the result differs) and (3) narrow the question down to just the code in question. Reading [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume from context that the methods belong to the `User` class. In that light

```
.where(User.id == cls.id) \
```

is effectively

```
.where(User.id == User.id) \
```

or just `where(True)`, and so every user is joined with every operation, when it probably is meant to be something like

```
.where(Operation.user_id == cls.id) \
```

though impossible to say due to lacking example. If the incorrect join does happen, it explains why the other user is returned by the query: it was joined with operations belonging to the correct user.

You also might have to add

```
.correlate(cls) \
```

before `as_scalar()`. The outermost select is also redundant, I think. You should be able to just

```
return (p - m).label('BALANCE')
```

Comment: Many thanks! What i need. A site did not give to publish all code. There a two tables in a base User and Operation. And User has many Operations.